# How to seperate 404 error codes subdomains from the 200 in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code, and what I am trying to do is to **seperate 400 response status codes subdomains.**
As you can see that I have provides three url's in **subdomains** list of index. Which have different status code

Now What I am trying to do is to seperate the 404 error status codes from them.

```
statuscode = []
statuscode.append(400) 
statuscode.append(403)
statuscode.append(404)

 subdomains = []
    subdomains.append("https://teyrtguhigkfjn.s3.amazonaws.com/")
    subdomains.append("http://google.com")
    subdomains.append("https://lasdfgfldsakjas.s3.amazonaws.com/")



    for x in subdomains:
        url =  x


        try:

            req = requests.get(url)

            req1 = str(req.status_code) + " " + str(url) + '\n'
            req2 = str(req.status_code)
            req3 = str(url)
            print "\n" + str(req1)

            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print "Can't make the request to this Subdomain " + str(url) + '\n'


    if statuscode in str(req1):

        print "\nTrying to Collect the URL's whose status is 400, 400, 403"
print str(req2) + ' ' + str(req3)
```

But I do not succeed in that. Please see the problem, and I think I know where is the problem it is in this line of the code **if statuscode in str(req1):**. **My Guess**

Hope you get the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
statuscode = [400, 403, 404]
subdomains = ["https://teyrtguhigkfjn.s3.amazonaws.com/", "http://google.com", "https://lasdfgfldsakjas.s3.amazonaws.com/"]

for url in subdomains:
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
        req1 = str(req.status_code) + " " + str(url) + '\n'
        req2 = str(req.status_code)
        print "\n" + str(req1)
        if req.status_code in statuscode:             #----->Update
            print "\nTrying to Collect the URL's whose status is 400, 400, 403"
            print str(req2) + ' ' + url
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print "Can't make the request to this Subdomain " + str(url) + '\n'
```

Comment: I did the same but I only get one url and i.e. `404 https://lasdfgfldsakjas.s3.amazonaws.com/` there are two url which have 404 error but I only get one. What about the first one i.e. `404 https://teyrtguhigkfjn.s3.amazonaws.com/`

Comment: You have a couple of errors in code. Updated snippet.

Comment: Hey! Thanks it working but There should be a seperate list for collecting the subdomains who have 404 error codes.

Comment: That is why I created a seperate code for it. `if req.status_code in statuscode:` but not work. So if you can create a seperate list then It will be great.

Comment: in that case use `if  req.status_code == 400: #append to list`

Comment: Hey! I am so sorry, I still don't get the First url. I added for loop for it. But still, I got only the third URL. I don't know what the exact problem is.